# Using the transclude clone attach function to add data accessible to transcluded content in Angular 1.5.8?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

I'd like to make a few selected properties of my component's controller visible in the scope of content transcluded into that component.  I'm trying to do that following Tero Parviainen's example for angular 1.4 here: http://jsbin.com/pibuqa/1/edit?html,css,js,output (from http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html).

I'm not having any luck in angular 1.5.8 though.  As far as I can tell, the alterations I make to $scope in the transclude clone attach function have no effect : http://plnkr.co/edit/Mr69lBZJswaM6MSyWwTP?p=preview

My goal:

`<my-component>
    <div>{{something}} will be set to "blah"</div>
<my-component>`

`component('myComponent', {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function ($transclude) {
         $transclude(function (transEl, transScope) { 
            transScope.something = "blah";
          }
     }})`

Edit: I believe I need to insert the transcluded text myself instead of relying on ng-transclude when doing this sort of thing.  (ng-transclude was transcluding the content on its own.  my clone attach function was running and doing nothing effectively, since it didn't manipulate dom.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is stemming from you using ng-transclude in your template and then calling $transclude in your controller. The content has been bound to the template and something property has been set on a different scope. You need to remove ng-transclude from your templates and append the content in your cloneLinkingFn:

```
$transclude(function (transEl, transScope) {
        // Set something property
        transScope.something = "something else";
        // Now append transcluded element to your element
        $element.append(transEl);
    });
```

Here is the updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4WWmyPcYuGmGh4dPGNmi?p=preview